# Darcula скин и схемы для PyScripter

Tags: python

Подскажите, как в PyScripter настроить тему и схему, схожую с Darcula в PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге сделал сам.

Качаем по ссылке: https://disk.yandex.ru/d/RyW_IQ24IhzuZw

Темы и стили кидаем по пути:
C:\ProgramData\PyScripter\

Вид - Стили: Darcula

Инструменты - Параметры - Свойства редактора - Color Theme: Darcula

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]